# Conversion of hex string to binary and count number without padding in mysql

Tags: mysql, binary, hex

I have a column which stores a hex number as a string in a mysql table.

I would like to convert to binary, and count the number of bits.

e.g.:

in the table description I have

```
hex_column     | text                | YES  |     | NULL
```

And an example of an entry in this column:

`0xFF`

Which when converted to binary gives:

`11111111`

So 8 bits. I am trying to do this conversion, and count the bits.

I guess I can convert to a string and use `LENGTH()` or use `BIT_COUNT()` directly to count the number of bits. But I am unable to get the hex number to convert to binary.

If I do:

```
select hex_str from my_table into @array;
CONV(@array,16,2);
```

I get a mySQL syntax error.

But:

```
SELECT @array; 
+--------+
| @array |
+--------+
| 0xFF   |
+--------+
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error was dues to not having a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CONV(@array,16,2);
```

But i also needed to get rid of the leading 0x for the conversion to work:

```
SELECT CONV(SUBSTRING(@array,3),16,2);
+--------------------------------+
| CONV(SUBSTRING(@array,3),16,2) |
+--------------------------------+
| 11111111                       |
+--------------------------------+
```

So to get the number of bits:

```
SELECT LENGTH(CONV(SUBSTRING(@array,3),16,2));
+----------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(CONV(SUBSTRING(@array,3),16,2)) |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      8 |
+----------------------------------------+
```